# How do I make image in fixed header negative color of anything that is under it while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a transparent fixed header that does not move when you scroll. In it, I have a black logo of my company.
What I need is that logo to change color every time it crosses over some item in page that has colors, specifically the negative color of the item under it.
the same thing had Palantir with their logo but they changed it.

I have googled a lot but can't find a solution, tried mostly blend mode in css but I am doing something wrong...

Comment: It's close to impossible to give a styling answer if there's no reproducible code provided. ".. *to change color every time **it** crosses over*.." by "it" are you referring to the mouse cursor hover, like do you need to style the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class?

Comment: @Aleksandar no, I mean when I scroll on my site, header is not moving . While scrolling, elements are basically moving under the header/logo. I need my logo to change the color every time some element is exactly under the logo, something like blending, but idk how to do it with various elements

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood you correctly, mix-blend-mode CSS property can help you, see this small example (you can experiment with mix-blend-mode value to choose the best result):

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  
}
p{
  background-color: #666;
}
p.red{
  background-color: red;
}
p.green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <img src="https://scontent.ftbs4-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t45.1600-4/338544317_6309992646707_2491776963105174437_n.jpg?stp=c220.0.540.540a_cp0_dst-jpg_p180x540_q75_spS444&_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=de7202&_nc_ohc=VcmdAB7SScMAX8pdXJ2&_nc_ht=scontent.ftbs4-2.fna&oh=00_AfA1HReZ3Zayt6dX7kuNbxiGjoZ4N_LSCxKbp231d4lOoA&oe=6428C2F8" alt="">
</div>
<p>
  minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?vv
</p>
<span>
Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possim
    <p class='red'>
  minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?vv
</p>us at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla 
  <p class='green'>
  minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?vv
</p>illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro verique voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dign nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro 
  <p class=red>
  minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?vv
</p>veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio
  <p class='red'>
  minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?vv
</p>minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus
  <p>
  minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?vv
</p>provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem 
  <p>
  minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?vv
</p>nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo repudiandae magnam quibusdam temporibus dignissimos minus porro fugiat molestias dolores natus alias mollitia, modi rem expedita. Aut ab aliquid eum commodi temporibus nesciunt natus voluptatum expedita nisi. Culpa sint soluta eos adipisci aut. Totam culpa doloremque voluptas quasi ipsum officia possimus quibusdam! Tenetur libero ipsam veniam porro veritatis eius rem nemo dolorem, possimus at blanditiis aliquam quisquam rerum saepe soluta ea tempora nostrum 
  </span>


<p>
  minima consequuntur vel deleniti ex, velit odio minus. Sunt, libero perspiciatis ex, deserunt repudiandae nulla illum omnis cumque mollitia rem quibusdam perferendis, optio molestias necessitatibus provident rerum. Ullam?vv
</p>
```

Comment: Yes you got it! I tried it and it kinda works:
since on some places I have a white logo and on some its black, I noticed that this works perfect on places where logo is white, but when it's black it does not work

Comment: Yep, it wont work with black, you may consider changing color to another dark color (e.g darkblue), and see how it will behave. Also you could use SVG filters for this, but this would be pretty difficult to do (for me at least). It is also possible to use JS to make it work, but it will be computationally expensive